# Operator precedence in addition and subtraction

Tags: notation, arithmetic, convention

Customary operator precedence has addition prior to subtraction. Apart from historical convention and notational consistency, is there a rationale for this?

Comment: Wait ... if + has precedence over - , then $3-4+7$ would evaluate to $3-11=-8$ ....but all of us would evaluate that to $-1+7=6$

Comment: I think you're wrong about "Customary operator precedence has addition prior to subtraction" both in math and in most programming languages. Is there a particular context that would override that? For instance, in math a mnemonic like PEMDAS/BEDMAS doesn't mean addition comes before subtraction - you also have to remember that they have the same precedence and addition/subtraction is resolved from left to right, as Bram28 commented.

Comment: See [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Definition) for the "customary" conventions. The rational reason for the conventions is that we need a rule.

Comment: It is common convention not to define subtraction and to interpret $a-b$ as $a+(-b)$, where $-$ is a unary operator. Since unary operators have precedence over binary ones, there is no ambiguity in what $3-4+7$ means. “Multiplicative unary symbols” have precedence over “additive” ones, so $-3^2$ is $-9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with @egreg, so let me elaborate on his comment.

The notation is rational because it is coherent with group theory. Indeed, $(\mathbb{Z}, + , 0)$ is an additive group, but it is interesting to first look at a multiplicative notation. If you write $xy^{-1}z$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are elements of a group, there is no ambiguity on the interpretation and nobody would interpret this as $x(yz)^{-1}$. If the group is commutative and comes with an additive notation, you would write $x - y + z$ instead, but again, it should not be interpreted as $x - (y +z)$.